# Ask again for the age if it does not equal a number

Tags: python

So, I've been making a text based adventure game and it asks you for your age. If your age is less than 13 it quits the game and if it is more or equal too it lets you play. What I'm trying to do now is make it so if the age is not a number it will ask you to renter the age, so sort of replay the script.

Is there any way of doing this?

```
age = input()

if age >= 13:
print("You are old enough to play! Let's get started!")

elif age != int:
print("This is not a number")
```

(That syntax doesn't work, plus I want it then to make you enter your age again for verification.)

```
else:
    print("You are not old enough.")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit("Please exit the console, you are too young to play.")
```

Comment: I'll edit it so it tells you, hang on.

Comment: Format your code properly

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    age = raw_input("Please enter your age > ")
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print "Please enter a number"
        continue
    else: 
        break

print "You age is {0}".format(age)

# Now do whatever you want with `age`
if age < 13:
    print "You are not old enough to play the game!"
    sys.exit(1)
```

This will repeatedly ask for you age until you finally give it a number, at which point it will break out of the loop.

Comment: Ah, thanks, how would I make it so if the age is less than 13 it system exits ( sys.exit() )

Comment: @Jonathan `if age < 13: sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
import sys
while True:
    age = raw_input("Please enter your age > ")
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        print "This is not a number"
    else:
        if age >= 13:
            print("You are old enough to play! Let's get started!")
            break
        else:
            print("You are not old enough.")
            sys.exit("Exiting the console, you are too young to play.")
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
try:
    age = int(input("How old are you?"))
except ValueError:
    print "Enter a valid number. (integer)."
else:
    if age >= 13: # if age is more than 12
        #run program
        print "Game starting!" # code for game loop would start here
    else:
        print "You are too young!" # if less than 13 is entered, this is run
        sys.exit("You must be 13 or above to play this game")
```

Comment: -1 what is `end()` function? Also, You haven't converted your raw_input to integer, it accepts all values currently. It also doesn't work for the case when a non integer is inputted.

Comment: @ansh0l Sorry! I amended post.

Comment: it still won't work if you input a text string. You need to catch the exception.

Comment: @ansh0I Sorry, fixed.